# inclusion of homotopy fiber and induced map on homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Given a fibration $F \to E \to B$, under what circumstances does the inclusion of the homotopy fiber into $E$, $F \to E$, induce injections on homology? The specific case I'm dealing with involves the fibration $F_n \to X_n \to X_{n-1}$ from a Postnikov tower of a space $X$ satisfying the condition that $X$ is path-connected and abelian, so the action of $\pi_1(X)$ on $\pi_n(X)$ is trivial for all $n>1$.

Under these conditions, I know that $F_n$ is a $K(\pi_nX,n)$, and the fact that $X$ is abelian means that $X$ has a CW approximation whose Postnikov tower consists of principal fibrations $X_n \to X_{n-1}$, but don't see how this helps me prove that the map on homology induced by inclusion, $H_n(F_n) \to H_n(X_n)$, is injective, which is what I'm trying to prove.

Of course, I realize that this induced map on homology map not be injective, in general, in which case I'd be grateful for a counterexample. Either way, thank you for your time.

Comment: The Hopf fibration $S^1\to S^3 \to S^2$ is a counter-example. I don't know offhand of a case where its true when its not trivially true( i.e. its trivially true when the fibration is the trivial one or the fiber is a homology ball). (Disclaimer: I am not an algebraic topologist.)

Comment: The Hopf fibration provides a counterexample for general fibrations, but not the specific case mentioned in the first paragraph, where the fibration is derived from a Postnikov tower. In this case, does the hypothesis hold?

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.  Observe that the map $F_n\to X_n$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_n$, and that the Hurewicz map $\pi_n(F_n)\to H_n(F_n)$ is an isomorphism since $F_n$ is $(n-1)$-connected.  Thus, the induced map $H_n(F_n)\to H_n(X_n)$ can be identified with the Hurewicz map $\pi_n(X_n)\to H_n(X_n)$, which is typically not injective.

For an explicit counterexample, take $X=S^2$ and $n=3$.  Note that $X_3$ is obtained from $X$ by adjoining cells of dimension $5$ and higher (to kill $\pi_4$ and higher homotopy groups), and so the map $X\to X_3$ is an isomorphism on $H_3$.  In particular, $H_3(X_3)$ is trivial, but $\pi_3(X_3)\cong \pi_3(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is nontrivial.